# Segmentation fault when creating a Phonon MediaObject

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, phonon

I have music playing program made using PySide which uses Phonon to playback audio. I updated to MacOS X Mavericks a few days ago, which meant I needed to reinstall PySide. I'm not sure which of these actions has caused this, but now whenever I try to create a Phonon MediaObject I get a Segmentation Fault: 11 from Python.

It's not just in my program, it happens when trying to create a MediaObject in Python without any other actions. I'm getting the following error message from my Mac whenever it crashes:

```
Process:         Python [13711]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [13707]
Responsible:     Terminal [13704]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-01 19:47:53.164 +1000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  C2686854-18CA-9D37-26E9-60050E3C4DA6

Sleep/Wake UUID: BB983BF6-CCE2-44D1-82A0-1C73382DFFE4

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008

VM Regions Near 0x8:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001082e8000-00000001082e9000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtCore                          0x000000010a1b34cb QObject::moveToThread(QThread*) + 17
1   QtDBus                          0x000000010d55f98b QDBusDefaultConnection::QDBusDefaultConnection(QDBusConnection::BusType, char const*) + 171
2   QtDBus                          0x000000010d55ebdf QDBusConnection::sessionBus() + 71
3   phonon                          0x000000010d50228d Phonon::FactoryPrivate::FactoryPrivate() + 189
4   phonon                          0x000000010d5024d5 Phonon::$_249::operator->() + 99
5   phonon                          0x000000010d502991 Phonon::Factory::registerFrontendObject(Phonon::MediaNodePrivate*) + 17
6   phonon                          0x000000010d50b27e Phonon::MediaNodePrivate::MediaNodePrivate(Phonon::MediaNodePrivate::CastId) + 80
7   phonon                          0x000000010d50f570 Phonon::MediaObjectPrivate::MediaObjectPrivate() + 24
8   phonon                          0x000000010d50be9d Phonon::MediaObject::MediaObject(QObject*) + 45
9   phonon.so                       0x000000010d42f24a Sbk_Phonon_MediaObject_Init + 458
10  org.python.python               0x0000000108338707 type_call + 189
11  org.python.python               0x00000001082f74fd PyObject_Call + 101
12  org.python.python               0x00000001083714f0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15525
13  org.python.python               0x0000000108373aaf fast_function + 182
14  org.python.python               0x0000000108370919 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12494
15  org.python.python               0x000000010836d721 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638
16  org.python.python               0x000000010836d0b5 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
17  org.python.python               0x000000010838beb8 run_mod + 53
18  org.python.python               0x000000010838bf5f PyRun_FileExFlags + 137
19  org.python.python               0x000000010838baad PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718
20  org.python.python               0x000000010839c58b Py_Main + 3039
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8e4fb5fd start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c938662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff923e743d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff923e7152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c937e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bd8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bdbfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c937e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bd8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bdbfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c937e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bd8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff90bdbfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007feba0d19700  rbx: 0x000000010d5b7098  rcx: 0x00000000002f4180  rdx: 0x000000000012c040
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007feba0d19700  rbp: 0x00007fff57917210  rsp: 0x00007fff579171d0
   r8: 0x00007feba0fd5d10   r9: 0x00007feba0ff5310  r10: 0x0000000019c04cbe  r11: 0x0000000070769b38
  r12: 0x00007fff57917220  r13: 0x00007feba0c07190  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007feba0fe1430
  rip: 0x000000010a1b34cb  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000008

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Anyone have any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: That it attempts to use d-bus on OS X is awkward

Comment: @NicholasSmith Qt 4.8

Comment: @LukeHansford: 4.8 has significant issues under Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from Qt 4.8.0 to Qt 4.8.5 seems to have fixed the issue.